# Unpublish form in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to un-publish form, not to delete it? I removed the link to the form from my website, but anyone with the link still can access the form.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely!  Under Form Settings in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) you can limit availability of your form to specific dates.  Just specify an end date to temporarily turn off your form!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the form name then no one will access  it directly